# Переключение таба при клике на ссылку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет, есть группа ссылок. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при клике на ссылку запускалась функция

```
 $.ionTabs.setTab("Tabs_Group_name", "Tab_1_name");
```

(Она открывает определенный таб).
Только вместо Tab_1_name должно быть Tab_(здесь указан номер порядковый номер ссылки по которой кликнули)_name.
Тоесть если кликают по первой ссылке, открывается первый таб, по второй-второй и тд. Представление как оно работать должно есть, но вот с решением проблемы возникли, надеюсь на вашу помощь
Код самих ссылок

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="leistungen.html#tab1">Beratung</a></li>
       <li><a href="leistungen.html#tab2">Jahresabschluss</a></li>
       <li><a href="leistungen.html#tab3">Finanzbuchhaltung</a></li>
       <li><a href="leistungen.html#tab4">Lohn- und Gehaltsbuchführung</a></li>
       <li><a href="leistungen.html#tab5">Steuererklärungen</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Покажите ссылки, какой там параметр.

Comment: html покажите пожалуйста

Comment: В общем в чем проблема сама тою На каждой странице сайта есть всплывающий при наведении блок, в котором содержаться эти ссылки. При клике на ссылку открыватся страница с табами и определенный таб, на который ведет эта ссылка. Так вот в хеше я записал значения и потом взависимости от них открывал определенный таб. Но проблема в том, что если использовать эти ссылки уже на открытой странице с табами, то табы не переключаются так как не происходит перезагрузка страницы. Поэтому и нужно прибегнуть к такому решению. Хтмл ссылок вверху